# How do I exclude some directories in a for loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop, unix, directory

I have created this loop but I want to exclude some directories from the job. I tried different ways but it keeps working on all directories. Can you please help me?

```
for d in */
    do
    cd $d
    echo $d
    cartel=$(echo ${d} | sed 's/\///')
    echo $cartel
```

I tried with:

```
 shopt -s extglob
 for d in this_folder/!(global|plugins|css)/   
      do    
      ...
      done
```

Comment: Please add what you tried and what issue you faced. But from the question you can have the names of directories to be excluded in a array and before you do things inside of the dir, check with an if  condition to see if it’s a dir you need to exclude.

Comment: `this_folder/!(global|plugins|css)/` - but directories inside `this_folder`  are not matched by `*/` - it's not recursive. You want to exclude `this _folder`? Or you want to exclude folkders named `./global` `./plugins` `./css`? Or you want to iterate over `for d in */*/` and exclude `./this_folder/global` `./this_folder/plugins` and `./this_folder/css`?

Comment: I want to iterate over for d in */ and exclude the folders named ./this_folder/global ./this_folder/plugins and ./this_folder/css

Comment: Do you want to recursively descend into each subdirectory in the hierarchy except for the named directories?

Comment: Yes, I need to do the same job in all the directories except the named directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can test explicitely for the directory you want to skip:
you can compare $d to the directories you want to avoid and go to the next loop using continue when you don't want to process this directory :

```
for d in */ ; do
    if [ "$d" == "global/" ] || [ "$d" == "plugins/" ] || [ "$d" == "css/" ] ; then
        continue
    fi
    cd $d
    echo $d
    cartel=$(echo ${d} | sed 's/\///')
    echo $cartel
    cd ..
done
```

Comment: In my case "global" folder not skyping in the itteration.  How to skip the above three folders.